# How to handle partial success in a batch of Tasks?

Tags: .net, error-handling, async-await

I have 3 Tasks that should run in parallel. I need to await all 3 and then continue processing their results. So something like:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
return process(results);
```

This works fine when all 3 tasks complete successfully. However, if one of them fails I get an exception that bubbles up all the way. This is not what I want. If any of these tasks throws an `InvalidOperationException` I can continue processing, I just need the `process` method to have access to the exception that was thrown.

I realize that I can `try...catch` within the tasks but that does not seem like it would be a hack. Beyond being semantically incorrect (the task DID fail - it should not return successfully), if I went with this approach, since the result can be successful OR return an exception, I would have to return a custom type. The `Task<T>` object however already exposes an Exception channel so I would prefer to not do double-duty and just use what is already present.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want something like `var combinedTask = Task.WhenAll(…); await combinedTask.IgnoreExceptions(); return process(combinedTask);`? Where `IgnoreExceptions()` would make it possible to `await` a faulting `Task` without throwing an exception. Or what exactly should `results` contain?

Comment: @svick - I agree, it seems that results cannot possibly be a consistent type. My thought is that I would need to work directly with the Task object here and not use the async/await facade. If I can ensure that all tasks run to completion regardless of errors then I can work with those task objects, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @svick - is `IgnoreExceptions()` something that exists? I can't find it.

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. It was just what I assumed you wanted, with syntax that could actually work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle this case like in my example below:

```
Task<T>[] tasks  = new Task<T>[] { task1, task2, task3 };

try
{
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch(InvalidOperationException exception) // If you need to handle any other exception do it
{
   // handle it if you wan to 
}

// You can use task1.IsFauled to know if current task failed, 
// and you can use task1.Exception to know why it failed

return process(tasks.Where(t => !t.IsFauled).ToArray());
```

Comment: so if task1 takes 1 seconds to run, task2 takes 2 and task3 takes 3 and task1 throws an error. Would task2 and task3 still complete in this situation? It seems like they would get cancelled.

Comment: Also, how would I know in this situation which task threw the exception

Comment: @GeorgeMauer How could they get canceled? `Task` can't get canceled just like that, that's done `CancellationTokenSource` and `WhenAll()` doesn't have access to anything like that.

Comment: Updated my answer. Yes Task.WhenAll will continue until all tasks will finish their work, maybe one of them will fail, maybe couple, but anyway it will wait all tasks. The difference will be only that `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` will throw AggregateException at the end if one of tasks will throw exception. After this you can use IsFauled and Exception properties of tasks to find who failed and why.

Comment: `await` doesn't throw `AggregateException`s, so your code wouldn't actually work.

Comment: @svick yep, sure, thanks, fixed to `InvalidOperationException`. I had it first but changed it in second change to `AggregateException`, because I thought that I had `Wait()`. not `await`.

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused again - if task1 fails, task2 succeeds, and task3 fails, will the catch block be invoked twice? @svick

Comment: @GeorgeMauer `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` will throw only first exception which will occur. You can change it to `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()`, which will throw AggregateException where you can get the list of all exception in property InnerExceptions. Also you can as I said before ask each task about the final state with IsFauled and Exception properties.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for this?

```
var tasks = new[] { task1, task2, task3 };
try { await Task.WhenAll(tasks); } catch (...) { }
return process(tasks);
```